# Office365: Strip specific email addresses in "To:" field with transport rules

Tags: email, mail-forwarding, exchangeonline, office365

I've setup a transport rule to redirect all messages from `support@ourdomain.com` to `support@ourdomain.supportsystem.com`.

The redirection is working fine, but the support system identifies `support@ourdomain.com` as a participant because it matches the `To:` field in the original mail header and that will trigger a notification to the same `support@ourdomain.com` address to confirm that a support ticket has been opened.

So the confirmation mail then will be redirected back to the support system and we have a loop.

For now I was only able to completely remove the `To:` field in Office365, but that will also remove legitimate extras addresses that would be interested on the issue.

The transport rule was basic:

```
Apply this rule if Is sent to 'suporte@ourdomain.com' or 'support@ourdomain.com'
Do the following:
* Set audit severity level to 'Do not audit' and 
* Remove this header: 'To' and
* Redirect the message to 'support@ourdomain.supportsystem.com' and 
* Stop processing more rules
```

My question: Is there a more elaborate way to create custom transport rules in Office365 to match the original address and remove only those who matches the rule?

Answer (score 3):

Just guessing:
You could try to delete the remove "To" action, and then add an "Except if" condition. Let notification emails not be redirected and exclude notification emails that will cause loops.